# Styling the Storage Access Framework directory picker

Tags: android

My application is intended for use in low-light environments and accordingly uses dark/muted colours - although I haven't implemented explicit dark theme support. In the app I am using an `android.content.intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` intent to access the SAF directory picker.

However the directory picker is displayed with a white background, which is visually jarring. Is there any way to style it via the intent, or some other mechanism, so that it uses a dark background?

Answer (score 1):

By using the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` think so it's not possible, because this is determined the default android system which can't be modified. For this you need to use the third-party library files like `Material Components`,`DarkModeKit`,`Carbon` and so on.